# Conflicts between 'for' and 'switch'?

Tags: java

I want to try a little programming that can read user input continuously unless input is `0`.

But the problem is whatever I enter (except `0`), it always shows *"Please choose one"* (in `default` part). If I enter `4`, it will show me this phrase twice!

I do not understand why. Is there a conflict between `for` and `switch` or something?

Here is code:

```
System.out.println("Help on:");
System.out.println(" 1. if");
System.out.println(" 2. switch");
System.out.println("Choose one: ");
char ch = (char)System.in.read();
while (ch!= '0') {
    switch(ch) { 
        case '1':
            System.out.println("The If"); 
            break;
        case '2':
            System.out.println("The Case");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Please choose one");        
    }
    ch = (char)System.in.read();         
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by ‘confits’? Surely it's not [the cooking term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confit).

Comment: He surely means "conflicts", please edit the title to correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `char ch = (char)System.in.read();`. Java does not support character based input very well, I recommend using a Scanner which fixes your output, however the user now has to press return after each input.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Switch
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("Help on:");
        System.out.println(" 1. if");
        System.out.println(" 2. switch");
        System.out.println("Choose one: ");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = in.nextLine();
        while (!s.equals("0"))
        {
            switch(s)
            {
                case "1":
                    System.out.println("The If");
                    break;
                case "2":
                    System.out.println("The Case");
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Please choose one");
            }
            s = in.nextLine();
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't want to press return, you can also read the character twice, although I can only speculate why this works is that there is a control character sent over the stream. Edit: I thought it could also be another byte of a UTF-16 character which is not used when typing in ASCII characters but System.in.read() returns integers not bytes.

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Switch
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("Help on:");
        System.out.println(" 1. if");
        System.out.println(" 2. switch");
        System.out.println("Choose one: ");
        char ch = (char)System.in.read();
        while (ch!= '0')
        {
            switch(ch)
            {
                case '1':
                    System.out.println("The If");
                    break;
                case '2':
                    System.out.println("The Case");
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Please choose one");
            }
            ch = (char)System.in.read();
            ch = (char)System.in.read();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`System.in.read()` reads a byte from the InputStream and returns it. When you type 1 or any single digit number  and press enter, it reads two characters.

Try tying multiple digit number to see how `System.in.read()` behaves.

You should use scanner for the console input:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html